# When creating a Doc using the standard constructor the model is not loaded [E029]

Tags: spacy

I'm trying to use SpaCY and instantiate the Doc object using the constructor:

```
words = ["hello", "world", "!"]
spaces = [True, False, False]
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words, spaces=spaces)
```

but when I do that, if I try to use the dependency parser:

```
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(chunk.text, chunk.root.text, chunk.root.dep_,
            chunk.root.head.text)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: [E029] noun_chunks requires the dependency parse, which requires a statistical model to be installed and loaded. For more info, see the documentation:
```

While if I use the method `nlp("Hello world!")` that does not happens.

The reason I do that, is because I use the entity extraction from a third party application I want to supply to SpaCy my tokenisation and my entities.

Something like this:

```
## Convert tokens
words, spaces = convert_to_spacy2(tokens_)

## Creating a new document with the text
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words, spaces=spaces)

## Loading entities in the spaCY document
entities = []
for s in myEntities:
    entities.append(Span(doc=doc, start=s['tokenStart'], end=s['tokenEnd'], label=s['type']))

doc.ents = entities
```

What should I do? load the pipeline by myself in the document, and exclude the tokeniser for example?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nlp()` returns a `Doc` where the tokenizer and all the pipeline components in `nlp.pipeline` have been applied to the document.

If you create a `Doc` by hand, the tokenizer and the pipeline components are not loaded or applied at any point.

After creating a `Doc` by hand, you can still apply individual pipeline components from a loaded model:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.tagger(doc)
nlp.parser(doc)
```

Then you can add your own entities to the document. (Note that if your tokenizer is very different from the default tokenizer used when training a model, the performance may not be as good.)